# Call a wowza server from android app?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, wowza

I'm trying to make some app that will play the stream from wowza. 
 That part is ok. But next i need to have some option in app, that will comunicate with wowza server. For example how to call a wowza server some method, how to call onConnect method ... How to connect from wowza from a app and stay connected until i call a onDisconnect method??? 
 If somebody have some info i will be very grateful... Thanks in advance...

```
VideoView.setVideoPath("some path")
```

does the trick for playing...

Comment: How did you play the stream from wowza. I need help in that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call call a method in a Wowza module using a HTTPProvider (http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?30-httpproviders). This gives you a url in your Wowza module which your app will be able to call over HTTP.

So for example you have your Wowza module running under the default of:

```
http://localhost:1935.
```

You can add a HTTPProvider to your VHost.xml, such as:

```
<HTTPProvider>
    <BaseClass>com.mycompany.wms.module.SomeModule</BaseClass>
    <RequestFilters>logout*</RequestFilters>
    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
</HTTPProvider>
```

This would let you call a url such as:

```
http://localhost:1935/logout?id=123456789
```

In the Java code for your module, you need implement HTTProvider2Base from which you create a onHTTPRequest method. The variables in the query string (so in this example: ?id=123456789) can be used in the method. You can also call methods in your module from here.

An example Java class that would use this call is as follows:

```
package com.mycompany.wms.module;

import com.wowza.wms.http.HTTProvider2Base;
import com.wowza.wms.http.IHTTPRequest;
import com.wowza.wms.http.IHTTPResponse;
import com.wowza.wms.logging.WMSLogger;
import com.wowza.wms.logging.WMSLoggerFactory;
import com.wowza.wms.vhost.IVHost;

public class SomeModule extends HTTProvider2Base {

public void onHTTPRequest(IVHost vhost, IHTTPRequest req, IHTTPResponse resp) {
    //Get the user
    String userId = req.getParameter("id");
    getLogger().info("Logging out user: " + userId );       

    logoutUser(userId);
}

private void logoutUser(String userId){
    //Do stuff here...
}

private WMSLogger getLogger(){
    return WMSLoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeModule.class);
}
}
```

Some gotchas:

- Scoping in onHTTPRequest seems to be outside of your instance so be careful of accessing properties in an instance of the module.
- I had to comment out the HTTPProvider node with HTTPServerVersion in it to get my one to work. It seemed to override all other HTTPProviders in my version of Wowza.
- I also had trouble with the Wowza running from the IDE not picking up calls to the url via Visual Studio. Once I put my changes into the service version, the calls worked fine.

The app I built which did this was largely based on the conversation in this article: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?182-HTTPProvider-that-returns-detail-server-info

Comment: Thanks man...this is very helpfull. Are you ever tried or even succeeded to get connection with a wowza server from android device like we can do in flash? I'm asking because i have i need, from time to time, to send information or call some method on a client side (android device)?!

Comment: Hi Jovan. I've not done it from an Android device. But I was thinking if you've got a url that you can use to call the wowza method, then you should be able to hit that url from your Android app? Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Nik, this is all very helpfull, and i get it, but i need to establish a connection like we have in a flash to flash app and in some, none defined time call some method on android client from server. For instance in chat app i need to send a msg from server to some android user? How can i achieve this? Do you have any thoughts?! Thanks for the time Nik! :)

Comment: Hi Jovan, I see what you're getting at. In flash we'd hook into a shared object and use that to do the callback but I'm not sure if you can do that from Android. But a workaround hack would be to set a url up on wowza that did a check for events for that user when called and then poll it regularly (for example every 30 secs). If something needed to happen on your android client then you could return the data back from the wowza url. Hope that helps, and hopefully you find a better solution!

Comment: Ok. Thanks Nik...i will try this, but because i didn't find any better solution, this workround will have to be for now... Thanks for the time and i will mark this for a good answer. Bye... :)